# Verify and select the right object in an array thanks to a find method which will match with a param json

Tags: node.js, arrays, json

I need some help,

I've got a json with some parameters inside of it, actually 2 but one day we may add some more in it.

I want to find between some object in an array the right one thanks to all parameters in the json

Am i using the right method ?

to be clearer, i want the `param.t` to match with the `element.t`, and the `param.tid` to match with the `element.tid` and if moving forward one more parameter `cd1` is added to the JSON, this `param.cd1` will match with `element.cd1`

thanks for the time !

```js
const array1 = [{"t":"pageview","de":"UTF-8","tid":"UA-xxxxxxxxxx-17","cd1":"Without cookie"},{"t":"timing","de":"UTF-8","tid":"UA-xxxxxxxx-1","cd1":"France"}];
const param = { t: 'pageview', tid: 'UA-xxxxxxxxxx-17' }

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(param)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
const obj = array1.find(element => element.t == param.t);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am following correctly, you want to compare an array of objects to an object and based on some keys in 'param' object you want to filter out your array1.

```
const array2 = [{"t":"pageview","de":"UTF-8","tid":"UA-xxxxxxxxxx-17","cd1":"Without cookie"},{"t":"timing","de":"UTF-8","tid":"UA-xxxxxxxx-1","cd1":"France"}];
const param1 = { t: 'pageview', tid: 'UA-xxxxxxxxxx-17' }

const test = array2.find(checkExist);

const checkExist = el => {
return el.t == param1.t && el.tid == param1.tid; // here you can add your keys in future
}
```

Comment: yeah that's what I wanna do, but is it possible to do it without the checkExist ?
If no, Thanks you answered my question :)

Comment: you need to pass an expression to find method if that evaluates to true, it return you the results in new Array.